# When did Rum change from "Rom" to "Ron" and why?

Tags: traducción, etimología

Run in Spanish is now, I believe, "Ron"; however, in older publications (such as "Treasure Island") the English word "Rum" is translated as "Rom"

Did "Rom" change to "Ron" because "Rom" was too easily confused with Vatican City and its environs, or what happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Rum* is the shortened version of the English *rumbuillon* and it came in Spanish as *ron* (easier to pronounce in Spanish). The [1817 edition of the Dictionary of the Real Academia Española](https://books.google.com/books?id=lR5JaGBj-nQC&pg=PA770#v=onepage&q&f=false) includes *ron* and I found no mention anywhere of *rom*, so it's probably just a typo. Does it appear only once or all around the book? Bear in mind you're reading a very old translation.

Comment: "Rom" is all throughout "Treasure Island"

Comment: @b.clay.shannon: translators do make mistakes.